# Searching a binary search tree not in order

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I have a binary search tree of objects that is ordered by a value x (objects with a lower value x are added to the left and those greater are to the right).

They also have an attribute y which is respectfully unordered. How would i got about searching through every node in the tree to find a match? and how would i return null if there was no match?

the code i currently have (which does indeed have many flaws hence why i am asking) is :

```
public BinaryTreeNode<E> inOrderIdSearch(BinaryTreeNode<E> n, int usrId) {
      if (n!=null) {
          inOrderIdSearch(n.getLeft(),usrId);
          if (n.getValue().getId() == usrId) {
            return n;
          }
          inOrderIdSearch(n.getRight(),usrId);
      }
      return null;
  }
```

Comment: Use [binary tree traversals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal).

Comment: If the tree is not ordered with respect to the value `y`, then you have to search every node in the tree, and the order of the traversal does not matter. If I were you, I would check the node first, and then go down the left and right subtrees.

Comment: I think i have the search bit down; how would i return null at the end if there was no match in the tree?

Comment: Also you are not returning the return value of the recursive calls.   You have to check the value of the first recursive call. If it's true, you return true and you're done with the current call.  Otherwise, you return the value of the second recursive call.

Comment: @Jonty "I think I have the search bit down".   Have you changed your code since you posted the question, because the code as you have it won't work.  As I mentioned, you're ignoring the search results from the recursive calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your tree is not ordered with respect to the value you're searching for, you have to search every node, and the order of the traversal does not matter. So search each node first, before going to its children.  Also you need to return the result of the recursive calls, rather than ignoring them as you have done above.

```
public BinaryTreeNode<E> inOrderIdSearch(BinaryTreeNode<E> n, int usrId) {
    if (n==null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (n.getValue().getId() == usrId) {
        return n;
    }
    BinaryTreeNode<E> leftResult =inOrderIdSearch(n.getLeft(),usrId);    
    if (leftResult!=null) {
        return leftResult;
    }
    BinaryTreeNode<E> rightResult = inOrderIdSearch(n.getRight(),usrId);
    if (rightResult != null) {
        return rightResult;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public BinaryTreeNode<E> inOrderIdSearch(BinaryTreeNode<E> n, int usrId) {
  if(n==null) return null;
  int candidate=n.getValue().getId();
  if(candidate==userId) return n;

  return inOrderIdSearch(candidate>userId?n.getLeft():n.getRight(),userId);
}
```